# Sorting New Grid Column in Sylius Error

Tags: sylius

I'm trying to get sorting to work on my new column in the Sylius admin 'Products' page, on the product grid. The column is mainTaxon, and I've gotten it to display correctly by adding a section to src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/product.yml

under 'fields':

```
mainTaxon:
    type: twig
    label: "Main Taxon"
    sortable: ~
    options:
        template: @SyliusAdmin/Product/Grid/Field/mainTaxon.html.twig
```

from the mainTaxon tempate I then render the main taxon if there is one, or else just a space character.

```
{% if data %}
    <a href="/admin/taxons/{{ data.id }}/edit">
        {{ data.name }}
    </a>
{% else %}
    &nbsp;
{% endif %}
```

This all works great for displaying the column with the main taxons. Unfortunately, as soon as I click on sort I get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Undefined index: mainTaxon") in
>   SyliusAdminBundle:Grid:_default.html.twig at line 41. 500 Internal
>   Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime

The line in the file that the error references is:

```
{% for row in data %}
```

This is the row loop that generates the entire grid for the product page. It seems to be having trouble before it ever gets to rendering the cell (td) that contains the mainTaxon, presumably because there is an array somewhere that I don't know about, which is missing the index for the extra category? Just a guess, insight appreciate!

*EDIT:*

I've done some further digging into this. Documentation on grid editing has been committed to Sylius since I asked this question: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/grid.html, though unfortunately it still does not address adding new fields.

I've taken a look at the Product.orm.xml file that maps the product ORM, and see that the mainTaxon field is mapped as follows:

```
<many-to-one field="mainTaxon" target-entity="Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Model\TaxonInterface">
    <join-column name="main_taxon_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

I think the issue must be that when a sort is performed a new query must be run to pull the product data from the database again, resorted. Clearly this mapping on the main_taxon_id column is entering the sort query incorrectly, presumably because it is a foreign key. I'm uncertain if foreign keys are not supported by the sorting functionality yet and this should be planned for the future, or whether there's something further I need to do to get this working.